# How to load resource javascript and css files using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The project I am working on has lots of javascript and css files.  I am using a corportate library that takes care of loading of the resource files by using something like this 
require("relative file name").
But for some of the pages I dont want to use this library and want to use plain jQuery. 
I cant use script or style tags to load my javascript (because my content is in iframe and sits in some other pages with a proxy - so all the urls get calculated at run time).
I can only use jQuery and Javascript to load these files.

Now I know I could use

```
$.getScript( <myFileURL>, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                  console.log( "Load was performed." );
                  if(jqxhr.status = 200){
                      //call another resource file?
                  }               
            });
```

The only thing is it seems an overkill to initiate so many async calls to load resource javascript files.  The processing can not go ahead unless all the resource files are loaded.  Is there any other way of loading all the resource files at once and then only proceed with the page once they are loaded.

EDIT:
tried this -

```
$.when($.getScript( <file1URL>),
               $.getScript( <file2URL>)).then(function(){
                customeFunction();// breakpoint here never gets hits.
          });
```

When I checked on network tab - I can see the files getting downloaded successfully.  But the customFunction() function never gets called.
Thanks

Comment: Could you bundle these files together on the server and just make on call to get them?

Comment: _"The only thing is it seems an overkill to initiate so many async calls to load resource javascript files"_ - To me it seems like overkill to reinvent your own loader (though using jQuery's promise implementation should deal with the problem of waiting for them all to load easily enough) when you already have a corporate library, or there's [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) or [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), etc.

Comment: thanks nnnnnnn... but I am not using the corporate library only for some very light weight pages - to help in the performance of page.

Comment: thanks nnnnnnn for mentioning require.js and yepnope.js.  interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) returns a [promise object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), so you can do this:

```
$.when($.getScript( "file1.js"),
       $.getScript( "file2.js"),
       $.getScript( "file3.js")).then(function(){
     //Your code.
});
```

The requests will be initiated without waiting for the previous one to complete. Once all scripts have been loaded the `then` handler will be called.

Or if you have an array of filenames:

```
files = ["one.js", "two.js", "three.js"];
promises = $.map(files, function(file){
    return $.getScript(file.valueOf());
});
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){});
```

Comment: is this supported in jquery 1.3?

Comment: @Tintin No, I think you would need 1.5. You could implement similar functionality yourself though, for example by looping through the files and incrementing a counter when each one loads. If the counter reaches the number of scripts you can call your handler function.

Comment: one more question - is there something special for loading css files as well? or do I just make ajax call and add its content with style tag on head pro-grammatically? thanks again.

Comment: I tried this but have one issue.  please see my edited question

Comment: Yeah, for CSS just do the same if you can get it via ajax, $.ajax also returns a promise object.

Can you try if a single `$.getScript("file.js").then()` works? Try adding an error handler instead of `then` to see if a request fails.